# Override PermissionEvaluator's hasPermission method for array of permissions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

How do optimize multiple `or` inside `hasPermission` here is how i am using inside my controller

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'user', 'DashBoard') or hasPermission(#user, 'user', 'Statistics') or hasPermission(#user, 'user', 'Graphs') or hasPermission(#user, 'user', 'Forum')
```

i wannt to have something like

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'user', 'DashBoard,Statistics,Graphs,Forum')
```

And want to overload `PermissionEvaluator` to handle the array of permission and evaluate.

Comment: This would be an overload, not an override.

Comment: @Turing85 exactly what i mean , let me edit it.